# TypeError: Return argument type tuple(int_const 23,bool,uint8[3] memory) is not convertible to expected type tuple(uint256,bool,uint256[3] memory)

Tags: solidity

When I compile and deploy below code. It gives me no error

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity ^0.8.0; 
contract MultipleValues{
    function returnValues() public pure returns (uint, bool, uint8[3] memory) {
        return (23, true, [1,2,3]);
    }
}
```

But when I change value from uint8[3] to uint[3] then it throws error

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract MultipleValues{
    function returnValues() public pure returns (uint, bool, uint[3] memory) {
        return (23, true, [1,2,3]);
    }
}
```

how to resolve this issue?

> Unexpected behaviour of array in solidity when returning a fixed size array

Answer (score 2):

Well the answer is in your question !
uint8[3] is not convertible to uint[3].

uint[] is the shorthand for uint256[]

If not explicitely assigned the array will be of the type of its values.
Since in your array all values are of uint8, the array is of type uint8[]

Here is the answer to your question (yes official docs generally have the answer you're looking for) :

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html#array-literals

[image]

so in your example this would work:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0; 
contract MultipleValues{
  function returnValues() public pure returns (uint, bool, uint8[3] 
memory){
return (23, true, [1,2,3]);
 }
}

contract MultipleValues2{

 function returnValues() public pure returns (uint, bool, uint256[3] 
 memory) {
  return (23, true, [uint256(1),2,3]);
 }
}
```

alternatively, having a uint256 value stored in the array would remove the need to declare the type:

```
contract MultipleValues2{

 function returnValues() public pure returns (uint, bool, uint256[3] memory) {
  return (23, true, [1,2,12300000200202020000002200200010100012002010102001020101020102222010122010012]);
 }
}
```